# How to get raw transaction from v, r, s signature

Tags: web3.py, python, cpp-ethereum

My question is what would convert transaction fields `r`, `s`, `v` to `rawTransaction`. Can I see a transaction in the `mempool` and get its signature and raw?

**here is an example `vrs`:**

```
raw = 0x02f8730128850532d935ca8509daf0fdca825208946b6950d7d56f82b2e8d97f76791f6e2507555db587015a79285a5f5880c001a07884ff67b26aba7bac53125c8a379575a0212f20ca2059bf44220c595dd2c016a049e4e1f2e99757bc07e3b41392593c087650b65e103d531b03d377354fc37965
r = 54512528383525145101142910442395400701618967938629024461348191366349363265558
s = 33423238519183062045415784622758412639724658679298157085289889201771832899941
v = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, it is not possible to directly convert transaction fields `r`,`s`,`v` to `rawtransction`. Because, the raw transaction is the serialized form of the transaction data, which includes the `r`, `s`, and `v` values, as well as other information such as the transaction nonce, gas price, gas limit, to address, value, and data.

But, if you have all the transaction data, you can convert it. In order to convert the `r`, `s`, and `v` values to a raw transaction, you need to reconstruct the entire transaction object. This includes calculating the Keccak-256 hash of the transaction data, something like this

```
# Create the transaction dictionary
transaction = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'gasPrice': gas_price,
    'gas': gas_limit,
    'to': to_address,
    'value': value,
    'data': data,
    'chainId': chain_id,
}
```

Once you have the entire transaction object, you can serialize it into a raw transaction using the `eth_sendRawTransaction` RPC method. This will return the raw transaction data.